# ui4j help on list with tabs

Tags: java, ui4j

I need to get some data from this [webpage](http://anaptyxi.gov.gr/ergopopup.aspx?mis=277649&wnd=). i need to click on the tabs but i just cant get them as Elements
The code from the FF inspector is:

```
<div id="dnn_ctr521_View_RadTabStrip2" class="RadTabStrip RadTabStrip_Outlook RadTabStripTop_Outlook pageTabs">
    <div class="rtsLevel rtsLevel1">
        <ul class="rtsUL">
            <li class="rtsLI rtsFirst">
                <a class="rtsLink rtsSelected" href="#">
                    <span class="rtsOut">
                        <span class="rtsIn">
                            <span class="rtsTxt">
                                Επισκόπηση
                            </span>
                        </span>
                    </span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="rtsLI">
                <a class="rtsLink rtsAfter" href="#">
                    <span class="rtsOut">
                        <span class="rtsIn">
                            <span class="rtsTxt">
                                Υποέργα
                            </span>
                        </span>
                    </span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="rtsLI"></li>
            <li class="rtsLI"></li>
            <li class="rtsLI rtsLast"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

I have tried everything i could think of, but nothing seems to work. The only thing that i got is to read the tabs with this
`document.query("#dnn_ctr521_View_RadTabStrip2")`
which is giving me this:

```
> WebKitElement [element=       <div class="rtsLevel rtsLevel1">            <ul
> class="rtsUL"><li class="rtsLI rtsFirst"><a class="rtsLink
> rtsSelected" href="#"><span class="rtsOut"><span class="rtsIn"><span
> class="rtsTxt">Επισκόπηση</span></span></span></a></li><li
> class="rtsLI"><a class="rtsLink rtsAfter" href="#"><span
> class="rtsOut"><span class="rtsIn"><span
> class="rtsTxt">Υποέργα</span></span></span></a></li><li
> class="rtsLI"><a class="rtsLink" href="#"><span class="rtsOut"><span
> class="rtsIn"><span
> class="rtsTxt">Πορεία</span></span></span></a></li><li
> class="rtsLI"><a class="rtsLink" href="#"><span class="rtsOut"><span
> class="rtsIn"><span class="rtsTxt">Εμπλεκόμενοι
> Φορείς</span></span></span></a></li><li class="rtsLI rtsLast"><a
> class="rtsLink" href="#"><span class="rtsOut"><span
> class="rtsIn"><span class="rtsTxt">Έγγραφα -
> Φωτογραφίες</span></span></span></a></li></ul>        </div><input
> id="dnn_ctr521_View_RadTabStrip2_ClientState"
> name="dnn_ctr521_View_RadTabStrip2_ClientState" type="hidden"
> autocomplete="off"
> value="{&quot;selectedIndexes&quot;:[&quot;0&quot;],&quot;logEntries&quot;:[],&quot;scrollState&quot;:{}}">
>   ]
```

but i cant go on from that

Comment: I like jsoup(http://jsoup.org/) for getting data from html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not required to click to the tab page to extract data. Tabs are already loaded with initial data.

```
package com.ui4j.sample;

import com.ui4j.api.browser.BrowserEngine;
import com.ui4j.api.browser.BrowserFactory;
import com.ui4j.api.browser.Page;
import com.ui4j.api.dom.Document;
import com.ui4j.api.dom.Element;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BrowserEngine engine = BrowserFactory.getWebKit();
        Page page = engine.navigate("http://anaptyxi.gov.gr/ergopopup.aspx?mis=277649");

        page.show();

        Document document = page.getDocument();

        // click to second tab
        document.queryAll(".rtsLI").get(1).click();

        // extract content from the first tab
        Element firstTab = document.query("#dnn_ctr521_View_pageEpiskopisi").get();
        String value = firstTab.query(".stoixeiaValues").get().getText().get();
        System.out.println(value); // prints 22.146.837 €

        // #dnn_ctr521_View_pageIpoerga second tab
        // #dnn_ctr521_View_pagePoreia third tab
        // #dnn_ctr521_View_pageForeis fourth tab
        // #dnn_ctr521_View_pageEggrafa fifth tab
    }
}
```

Comment: very nice! thanks! how on earth did you see that i have no idea! thanks